# Fixed texture size (Pixel) libgdx, java

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, pixel

If I resize the window (e.g. fullscreen) the texture size also changes!

I want that behaviour: If I change to fullscreen you will see more of the game world. The size (Pixel) of the texture stay the same. Not a scaling.

Thanks.

Regards,
Matthias

Answer (score 3):

In your main `ApplicationListener` where you create a camera object there will also be a resize method. If not override/implement it. It takes two arguments and when the window is resized these will be the dimensions of the newly resized window. Just set the cameras size to the new window size and call `camera.update();` Should sort it! (I assume you are using the built in `OrthographicCamera` class of Libgdx)

Hope this helps